# SOCKS Protocol Version prior to SOCKS4

Tags: proxy, socks

I saw SOCKS protocol have the version 4 and version 5, which can be referenced from:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1928 
http://www.openssh.com/txt/socks4.protocol

My question is:
Does SOCKS exist version 1 , version 2 or version 3 prior to version 4(SOCKS4)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there were earlier versions of SOCKS prior to version 4, as evident by the following comment in the SOCKS v4 protocol spec:

http://ftp.icm.edu.pl/packages/socks/socks4/SOCKS4.protocol

> SOCKS was originally developed by David Koblas and **subsequently modified
>   and extended by me to its current running version -- version 4**.

This is also mentioned in QNX's SOCKS reference:

http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.5.0/topic/com.qnx.doc.neutrino_lib_ref/socksappendix.html

> The original SOCKS was written by David Koblas (koblas@netcom.com). The SOCKS protocol has changed over time. The client library shipped as of printing corresponds to SOCKS v4.2. Since the server and the clients must use the same SOCKS protocol, **this library doesn't work with servers of previous releases; clients compiled with these libraries won't work with older servers**.

And no, you don't need to bother worrying about those earlier versions, as nobody actually uses them anymore.  SOCKS4 is the minimum version still in use, though SOCKS4A and SOCKS5 are preferred.